# Pattern.compile java

Tags: java, regex

How can I write a rule for a document there are these three words "at work", "Alan Turing", "Manchester University"? I tried to write:

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("work at && Alan Turing && Manchester University");
```

but it does not work, I do not find anything in a document with the three words!

Comment: What `Pattern` are you talking about? Is this about regex? In that case, have you even looked at a regular expression before? And what does your question have to do with design patterns? Did you even read the tag description for that?

Comment: Are you trying to search a repository of documents for documents that contain those three phrases? In any order?

Comment: You need to read up on regex documentation. Take a look here for starters: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex for this case. Assuming the document text is stored as the string `document`, you can do the following:

```
boolean isDocumentValid = document.contains("at work") && 
                          document.contains("Alan Turing") &&
                          document.contains("Manchester University");
```

Comment: Won't it incorrectly match `cat work` or `BAlan Turing`?

Comment: It will, but we don't know if that is good or bad :)

Comment: Indeed, but it's hard to tell exactly how meticulous the OP wants to be. I'd wager a guess that this is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is little bit vague but probably positive lookahead will solve your problem:

```
(?=.*?\bwork at\b)(?=.*?\bAlan Turing\b)(?=.*?\bManchester University\b)^.*$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/MG6eih4syb

Comment: shouldn't `bague` be `vague`? (just asking since I am learning English :)

Comment: @Pshemo: lol :) you're right, don't know who thought of putting `b` next to `v` in these keyboards :P

Comment: Personally I would split that up in three separate regex'es and fire a lookup separately. No need for those hard to understand constructs.

Comment: @owlstead: They aren't that hard to understand. It simply does a lookahead for 3 strings that OP is interested in. Strings have been wrapped between `\b` (word boundary) to avoid matching unwanted similar strings.

Comment: I'm with you regarding the word boundaries (which are very nice to use in this case). I'm not so sure if I like the positive lookahead - I don't think much of e.g. the stackoverflow population is familiar with those.

Answer (score 0):

The Java `Pattern` class is an implementation of Regular Expressions or Regexes.  What you have written looks nothing like a regex ... or any other text pattern matching language I've ever seen.

You can find tutorials on Regular Expressions in lots of places; for example:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Once you've got a handle on how regexes work, the javadoc for the `Pattern` class has a concise summary of the syntax in the class overview [section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

In fact, regexes are a poor choice for this particular problem.  If you want search a document to see if it contains two or more phrases in no particular order, then the best way to do it is search for each of the phrases in turn, and then combine the result of the 3 matches.

If you try to solve this with a single regex, you need a complicated pattern to find them irrespective of the order they appear.  You either need something obscure using lookaheads / lookbehinds, or use a pattern that enumerates the permutations; e.g.

```
"A.*B.*C|A.*C.*B|B.*A.*C|B.*C.*A|C.*A.*B|C.*B.*A"
```

where `A`, `B` and `C` are subpatterns that match the respective phrases.

Doing 3 separate regex matches (using `Matcher.find()`) or simple String matches (using `String.contains(...)`) will be easier to understand<sup>1</sup> and probably more efficient.

---

<sup>1 - Whether you label this "easy" or "hard" to understand depends on your familiarity with regexes.</sup>